# Check if git remote exists before first push

Tags: git, bash

I'm writing a bash script and I need a test to see whether a given remote exists.

Suppose, for concreteness, that I want to test whether the remote `faraway` exists. If I've pushed something to `faraway`, I can do `if [ -d .git/refs/remotes/faraway ]; then ...`. But as far as I can see, the alias `faraway` can still be defined even if `.git/refs/remotes/faraway` does not exist.

One other option is to parse through the output of `git remote` and see if `faraway` appears there. But I'm wondering whether there is an easier way of checking whether `faraway` is defined, regardless of whether `.git/refs/remotes/faraway/` exists.

Comment: See also: [Super User: git "ping": check if remote repository exists](https://superuser.com/q/227509/425838)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One thought: You could test exit status on `git ls-remote faraway`. This will actually force communication with the remote, instead of just looking for its presence or absence locally.

```
if git ls-remote --exit-code faraway; then
    ....
fi
```

Comment: @apc Ah ha. Yeah you'll want to redirect to `/dev/null`. The `--quiet` flag was [added to silence a single line](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cefb2a5e39b165146aee3b093872721cc1155a87) when `git ls-remote` is issued without argument.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the --quiet flag but didn't seem to work. Is it worth editing the original answer to include that? Not sure what the etiquette is...

Comment: @apc In general make any edit you feel significantly improves an answer. SO is community-owned and depends on the community for maintenance. Feel free to add the `/dev/null` redirection if you'd like. The only reason I left it out is that there are a few outputs to redirect, and I wasn't sure if you wanted it totally silent or to return errors, etc.

Comment: @AchillesGasperRasquinha Your edit to fix the syntax actually broke it. `[[` and `test` can't be used together. It's one or the other.

Answer (score 47):

Another way to check if `faraway` is defined in `.git/config`:

```sh
if git config remote.faraway.url > /dev/null; then
  …
fi
```

To check if `faraway` *isn't* defined, prefix the condition with `!`:

```sh
if ! git config remote.faraway.url > /dev/null; then
  …
fi
```

Comment: This helps especially if you want to prevent remote roundtrips.

Comment: What is the best way to check for the negative, if it isn't defined?

Comment: @rveach Just prefix with `!`, so `if ! git config remote.faraway.url > /dev/null; then`

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Exit code of command is used and there is no comparison, so no brackets are needed

Answer (score 11):

If the remote is defined in `.git/config`, you can avoid pinging the remote server with `git remote`.

```
if git remote | grep faraway > /dev/null; then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: That is a substring search, so it could give false positives if you have other remotes containing `faraway`.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and most-reliable way I've found in bash is this:

```bash
if timeout 30s git ls-remote --tags > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Note: it takes 2~4 sec to get to here.
    echo "git server IS available"
else
    # Note: it takes 30 seconds (as specified by `timeout`) to get to here.
    echo "git server is NOT available"
fi
```

Optionally increase the `timeout 30s` value to a larger number of seconds if your server is unable to respond under normal conditions within that amount of time.

For a full and detailed explanation, see my main answer here: [Fastest way to check if a git server is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297645/4561887).

Note that I do *not* recommend using the `--exit-code` option, due to what [@Jo Liss said here](https://superuser.com/questions/227509/git-ping-check-if-remote-repository-exists#comment1232690_833286):

> `-h` is a great idea. However, `--exit-code` is not the right choice here. The man page says: *Exit with status "2" when no matching refs are found in the remote repository.* This means that `git ls-remote --exit-code "$REPO_URL"` will fail for an empty repo that has only just been initialized with `git init`.

Also, I most-definitely recommend using `--tags` over `-h` or `--heads` in order to make this command as fast as possible when the git server *is* available. See my speed comparisons [in my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73297514/4561887). Here they are again for your convenience. Using `--tags` consistently takes 2~4 sec, whereas `--heads` takes 3~10 sec.

```bash
# 4~25 sec
# 218467 lines
time git ls-remote | wc -l

# 3~18 sec
# 218076 lines
time git ls-remote --refs | wc -l

# 3~10 sec
# 43337 lines
time git ls-remote --heads | wc -l

# 2~4 sec
# 9769 lines
time git ls-remote --tags | wc -l

# 0.002 ~ 0.008 sec
# But worthless! It passes even if the remote is not available!
time git ls-remote --get-url

# 4~25 sec
# 1 line
time git ls-remote origin HEAD
```

See also [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297514/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-git-server-is-available#comment129446631_73297514):

> @torek, for your reference, it's a massive > 100 GB GitHub Enterprise mono-repo, with 218467 objects returned by `git ls-remote`. I tested repeatedly, and `git ls-remote --tags` is very consistently a lot faster than `time git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD`. I suspect it's because there are fewer `--tags` than `--heads` to search through and the latter requires finding all `--heads` and then linearly searching through them to find the match to `HEAD`. (I'm guessing on the linear search assumption here--trying to explain observations I am seeing, not predict observations I am not).