# Check that git repository exists

Tags: git, github

Is there any way how to check whether git repository exist just before perform `git clone` action? Something like `git clone $REMOTE_URL --dry-run`?

I would like to implement fast checking method which will check existence before the clone action will be performed. I expect that connection might be slow and repository might be big even more than 1GB, so I don't want to rely on time extensive operation due to simple validation. The clone will be performed asynchronously in the background when validation passes.

I found this https://superuser.com/questions/227509/git-ping-check-if-remote-repository-exists but it works from git repository context after initial clone action is done.

Maybe there is some git call which works without git repository context and return "some data" if repository on destination exist or error if doesn't.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The answer that you linked does what you want it to do.

Try running this in a folder without a repository in it:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git
```

It should show you the references on the remote, even though you haven't added a local repository with `git init` or done a `git clone`.

See more: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html

Comment: I've tried ls-remote usage before I asked for help here, but didn't worked. Now I realized, that I was restricted by proxy.

Comment: +1 for universal solution without depenency on github api only.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from a bash script? Something that can be tested with an if/else statement?

Comment: `git ls-remote git@github.com:johndoe/my-cool-repo.git` <- you won't be asked to authenticate if you pass a git url instead of https

Comment: There are a bunch more answers on this [here](https://superuser.com/q/227509/425838) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12170459/4561887). I just added one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298218/4561887), which shows how to print out whether the remote is available or not, and allows setting a timeout for when the remote server is not available. One just needs to add in the URL is all, to my answer, as you have in your answer here.

Answer (score 12):

You can easily do this using [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) (make sure to leave out `.git` from the repo name):

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>
```

If the repository is not found:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/coldhawaiian/blarblar
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Otherwise:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/coldhawaiian/git-ninja-toolkit
{
  "id": 11881218,
  "name": "git-ninja-toolkit",
  "full_name": "coldhawaiian/git-ninja-toolkit",
  "owner": {
    "login": "coldhawaiian",
    "id": 463580,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/463580?",
    "gravatar_id": "f4de866459391939cd2eaf8b369d4d09",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/coldhawaiian",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/coldhawaiian",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/coldhawaiian/followers",
    // etc...
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Of course, this only helps if the remote is hosted on GitHub. The `ls-remote` solution should work with any remote.

Comment: For Bitbucket, the following URL can be used:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{user}/{repo_name} 

If the Repository doesn't exist: it returns `{'message' : Repository user/repo_name not found}`

If the Repository exists, it returns `Forbidden`. Which isn't exactly informative, but it works.

Comment: The other benefit of git ls-remote is it works for private repositories if you are authenticated in command line.

Comment: Fwiw, this [doesn't seem to work for wikis](https://github.community/t/api-for-repositorys-wiki/902) unfortunately. Guess I'll have to use the `ls-remote` method.

Comment: Another downside of using GitHub API is the fact that there is a limit on GitHub API requests (60/min if not authenticated), but with `ls-remote` there is no such a limit.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`ls-remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html):

```
$ git ls-remote git@github.com:github/markup.git
794d5d36dae7c1a9a0ed3d452ad0ffa5ab2cc074    HEAD
d27b5b1c5ae84617d4a9356eaf565c7b555c4d1d    refs/heads/can_render_regex
c03cce8f271d683c9cdeb5253c9cb21b5f0e65a0    refs/heads/fix-tests-part-deux
# Snip many more lines

$ git ls-remote git@github.com:nothing/here.git
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note that `ls-remote` exits 128 when this occurs, so you could redirect the command output if you don't need it and just check the command's return value.

Note that in some cases you may get prompted for input, e.g. if you try to access a GitHub `https://...` repository. This is because there may be a matching private repository.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/repos/user/repository-name
```

If the Git repository does not exist, the output will be:

```
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

If the Git repository exists, the output will be:

```
{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "repository-name",
    "full_name": "user/repository-name",
    "owner": { ... } 
    ............
}
```

Comment: nice, but original goal was to "ping any repository" not only those which are hosted on github.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a `HEAD` request to `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

If the public repository exists, the output will be:

```
200
```

Otherwise it will be:

```
404
```

Answer (score 0):

#### git command

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git HEAD && echo repoExists || echo notExists
```

#### curl

```
curl https://github.com/git/git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack && echo notExists || echo repoExists
```

#### JavaScript

Source Code

https://github.com/hellowork-mhlw/hellowork-mhlw.github.io/blob/main/api/github.js

```js
async function handler(url) {
  const exists = await fetch('https://hellowork-mhlw.vercel.app/api/github?url=' + url).then(r => r.json())
  if (exists) {
    document.all.out.value = 'exists'
  } else {
    document.all.out.value = 'not exists'
  }
}
```

```html
<input value="https://github.com/git/git" placeholder="https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell.git" oninput="handler(this.value)" size=35>
<output id=out>exists</output>
```