# Fastest way to check if a git server is available

Tags: bash, git

I need a *fast* (< 30 seconds) way to see if a git server is available. Assume the repo is already set up and you've already pushed to it.

I've read these already and they are related but not my question:

1. [Super User: git "ping": check if remote repository exists](https://superuser.com/q/227509/425838)
2. [Check if git remote exists before first push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12170459/4561887)

Here is what I've tried so far. Note that I piped the output to `wc -l` just to count the lines so I could get a feel for how that affected the time it takes. Notice that I'm using `git ls-remote` in all of my command attempts:

```bash
# 4~25 sec
# 218467 lines
time git ls-remote | wc -l

# 3~18 sec
# 218076 lines
time git ls-remote --refs | wc -l

# 3~10 sec
# 43337 lines
time git ls-remote --heads | wc -l

# 2~4 sec
# 9769 lines
time git ls-remote --tags | wc -l

# 0.002 ~ 0.008 sec
# But worthless! It passes even if the remote is not available!
time git ls-remote --get-url

# 4~25 sec
# 1 line
time git ls-remote origin HEAD
```

As you can see, `time git ls-remote --tags | wc -l` is the best, because it only takes 2~4 sec instead of 4~25 sec when the git server is available. However, when the git server is *not* available, all of the commands except the `time git ls-remote --get-url` one (which is worthless anyway since it passes even when the server is *not* available) take 2.5 **minutes** or so!

**How can I set their timeouts to return in 30 seconds if the server is not available?**

Is there a way to `ping` the server instead?

Comment: `git ls-remote` or similar is your best bet since it can (usually does) call up the remote and force it to respond. To limit how long it takes to respond, add arguments *to* whatever command you run to make it as easy as possible for the potential remote to respond, e.g., ask for `--symref ` and `HEAD`. Example: `git ls-remote --symref $(git config --get remote.origin.url) HEAD`

Comment: Do you want `timeout 30s git ls-remote --get-url`?

Comment: @torek, thanks. I tried `time git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD` and it is actually *slower* than `time git ls-remote --tags` when the server _is_ present, and it still takes 2.5 *minutes* or so when the server is *not* present.

Comment: Well, yes: if nobody answers at all, you wait for a standard timeout. So add some sort of front end timeout, like @funnydman's `timeout 30s`. The speed will depend on caching at the remote; `--tags` should generally be slower since they must find all tags, while asking just about `HEAD` should be quickest since they've already read `HEAD` to verify that it's a Git repository, *if* it's a CGit based Git. If it's JGit, who knows.

Comment: Note that "no response" timeout is up to your OS's TCP implementation. Your system sends a SYN packet and waits, and if nothing comes back, maybe the SYN got lost, so it sends another one and waits, and repeats some configured number of times with some configured waits and backoff rate, and then gives up.

Comment: The amount of time taken when you *do* get a response depends entirely on the server. Using `--tags` means *ask the server for tags only*, so the server will do server-side filtering for all tags. This could be very rapid (milliseconds) if there are almost no tags, or take minutes or hours on very slow CGit servers. JGit uses a prebuilt table of refs so the filtering is linear in the number of refs, and pretty quick. Then you'll spend some network time reading the responses.

Comment: @torek, for your reference, it's a massive > 100 GB GitHub Enterprise mono-repo, with 218467 objects returned by `git ls-remote`. I tested repeatedly, and `git ls-remote --tags` is _very consistently_ a lot faster than `time git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD`. I suspect it's because there are fewer `--tags` than `--heads` to search through and the latter requires finding all `--heads` and then linearly searching through them to find the match to `HEAD`. (I'm guessing on the linear search assumption here--trying to explain observations I am seeing, not predict observations I am not).

Comment: Aha: it's probably not JGit then. it's unfortunate that `--symref ... HEAD` tries to produce the commit hash ID for `HEAD` rather than just dumping out the symbolic name only (which would be much faster). There's been O(n^2) behavior in some of the filtering code in CGit though, so watch out for these cases. (Also, "theoretically faster" or "should be faster" doesn't do us much good when the code is terrible. I'm sort of anxious for Git to acquire a reftables implementation...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fastest way in bash to see if a git remote server is available or exists

[Thank you @funnydman!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297514/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-git-server-is-available/73297645#comment129446347_73297514) I was not aware of the `timeout` command at all. See `man timeout` for details.

This works!: prefix the command with the `timeout` command to kill it after the specified timeout if it's still running:

```bash
time timeout 30s git ls-remote --tags | wc -l
```

Or, better yet: discard all stdout and stderr output by writing it to the `/dev/null` pseudo-file. Note: `2>&1` redirects stderr (file descriptor `2`) to stdout (file descriptor `1`) <sup>Note 1</sup>:

```bash
time timeout 30s git ls-remote --tags > /dev/null 2>&1
```

That's the absolute fastest command I get get when the server is up (2~4 sec), and it times out after the specified number of seconds (30 in this case) when it is down. Thank you!

**Final answer:** here is a full bash script then:

```bash
if timeout 30s git ls-remote --tags > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Note: it takes 2~4 sec to get to here.
    echo "git server IS available"
else
    # Note: it takes 30 seconds (as specified by `timeout`) to get to here.
    echo "git server is NOT available"
fi
```

Optionally increase the `timeout 30s` value to a larger number of seconds if your server is unable to respond under normal conditions within that amount of time.

**Note 1:** `stdin` = file descriptor `0`, `stdout` = file descriptor `1`, `stderr` = file descriptor `2`. The `&` symbol is used to take a reference of a file descriptor, apparently, so `2>&1` redirects `2` to the same output stream as `1`. `> /dev/null` directs the `stdout` output stream to the `/dev/null` pseudo-file to discard it, so `> /dev/null 2>&1` combines those two things together, redirecting stderr to stdout, and writing stdout (which now contains stderr as well) to `/dev/null`.

### See also

I've also now posted snippets of the above information in my other answers here:

1. [Check if git remote exists before first push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298218/4561887)
2. [Super User: git "ping": check if remote repository exists](https://superuser.com/a/1736247/425838)
3. The above code snippet is now used by my cron job script here: [repo_git_pull_latest.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/cronjobs/repo_git_pull_latest.sh)

Comment: I'm glad it helped in some way :)